# Issue with POST URL when using Joomla's jRoute library

Tags: php, javascript, joomla

I am using Joomla's jRoute library, and my console request url is `Post http://localhost/jfirst/index.php/en/hospital` while I need this type of console url `Post http://localhost/jfirst/`

```
function get_state(e) {
    $js.ajax({
        url: "<?php JRoute::_('') ?>",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            'option': 'com_doctors',
            'view': 'hospital',
            'task': 'get_state',
            'id': e
        },
        beforeSend: function() {


        },
        success: function(res) {
            $js('#city').html(res.html);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The tags for your question are a bit misleading because the issue is with the `JRoute` call which is a very specific library. Moreover, even though you are using jquery, it is irrelevant to the issue. Try to retag your question to get more relevant views.

Comment: it seems we dont have any tag with name JRoute at SO and i dont have privilege to create a new tag.

Comment: Add it to the title, it's better than nothing :) And add a joomla tag in there too, I'm sure it will help

Answer (score 0):

try using `<?php JRoute::_('index.php') ?>`

Answer (score 0):

i have found ans the ques myself, i have used url: "", and its working fine.